# How to turn off in Intellij idea attemps to remember and restore opened files when checkouting different branches/commits

Tags: intellij-idea

There is a way how to turn it off somewhere, but I cannot find it again. Any time I checkout different commit, intellij idea tries to restore session for me, which I totally don't want. I have already disabled everything which can be disabled in change lists settings. Can anyone advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default IntelliJ restores the workspace of a branch when switching to it, which can be disabled in **Settings > Version Control > Confirmation**:

[image: Restore workspace option]